# Gibberish Characters in Redhat

Tags: rhel, fonts

On one RHEL Server I installed Arabic Language support but if browse some Arabic or Urdu Language sites it is showing gibberish characters.

So I downloaded some fonts and copied them under `home/.fonts` and for system wide I copied them under `/usr/share/fonts/`.

And refreshed the `fc-cache` but still fonts are not rendering.

Any Suggestions on it??

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61243/how-to-verify-if-the-language-is-installed

Comment: Different kinds of gibberish may signify different problems. What are you seeing, exactly?

Comment: @n.m. If i visit some Urdu or Arabic sites it is showing some missing characters in words. Actually some of our webapplications also has the Arabic support. But those are not rendering properly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be in one of several places. In your web browser, try changing the Character Encoding to UTF-8 or ISO-8859-6. To do this in the latest Firefox, you must hold `Alt-V` to open the hidden View menu.

You might want to try pasting the gibberish into a gibberish decoder, here is one that I wrote and many Israelis use it regularly:
http://gibberish.co.il/gibberish.html

The page is in Hebrew, but it should work on your Arabic text as well. I added Arabic as we have a large Arabic minority in Israel. Let me know which works (changing encoding, or the gibberish decoder, or both) and we should be able to progress.